# Floating point algorithm instruction (FYLXP1) returns 0

Tags: assembly, floating-point, masm

I am attempting to use the instruction FYL2XP1, but it seems the result is always 0, so I do not know what I am doing wrong. Keep in mind, I am a beginner in assembly.

Here is my code. I use MASM and call it from within my C code:

```
IFDEF RAX
ELSE
.Model Flat, Stdcall
ENDIF

INCLUDELIB msvcrt.lib
printf PROTO C, :VARARG

.Data

szFormat DB "%.09f", 10, 0

fVal1 TBYTE 10.0
fVal2 TBYTE 10.0
fRes TBYTE 0.0

.Code

FYL2XP1Func Proc
FLD fVal1
FLD fVal2
FYL2XP1
FSTP TBYTE PTR [fRes]
INVOKE printf, OFFSET szFormat, OFFSET fRes
RET
FYL2XP1Func Endp
Public FYL2XP1Func
```

Comment: What are you assembling this as, a 16-, 32-, or 64-bit binary? The ten byte floating point data type (`long double`) was dropped with the 32 bit C compiler, IIRC.

Comment: `%.09f` takes a `double` by value, not a pointer-to-10byte (which you're doing with `offset`).  And as @1201ProgramAlarm says, MS's C library doesn't even have a conversion specifier for the 10-byte x87 type. You can use it in asm, but you can't AFAIK print it with `printf` from that library.  I think MingGW or Cygwin might have a printf where `%Lf` would work for that type, otherwise print it manually somehow or convert it to 64-bit `double`.